# Is it possible to generate assembly code directly from a well-formed AST without translate to IR?

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, llvm-ir

I have a toy interpreter implements with LLVM & C++（generate LLVM IR by walking AST and run with JIT, language based on Perl, with build-in data structures and functions）.Now I want to expand it to a compilable one, generates assembly code and get executable with gas and ld.

If what i want is just a runnable compiler that creates a "JUST CORRECT" elf executables without complex optimizations, must I translate AST to IR like RTL or something like that? Or there is alternative choices instead of building AST in syntactic analysis phase?

By the way，I want to know that in small compilers like lcc or tcc, what's the "IR“s and ”object code“ of it ?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use LLVM for that? Since you already generate LLVM IR, there's zero effort to let LLVM generate assembly / object files from that.... Unless you need some runtime support.

Answer (score 5):

You can build assembly code for many procedural langauges by walking the AST and generating machine instructions that accomplish the work implied by the AST nodes being visited.  Usually one adopts a push-down stack model of expression evalution for this task, because the code generator done this way isn't smart enough to allocate registers effectively.  But, you can get working assembler code this way.

Don't expect this to get you *good* code.   But you can likely build one these pretty fast.  (Expect to have to generate some disgusting assembler, e.g.,  "push X, push Y, pop EAX, pop EDX, add EAX,EDX, push EAX")

You will likely need to build up symbol tables containinng at least information about the types of your declared variables.  You really need to know that "I" in an integer, before you generate "push I" as a machine instruction.  (Floating point values and strings need to produce different code).

If you haven't built a compiler before, doing one this way is a great experience.  You get a working compiler pretty fast, and you learn a lot about why real compilers use IRs to enable code optimization.